# XML DTD Validation error

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

Hello I just started to learn XML and DTDs and I cannot get my code to validate.  I am using http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/ to validate my code.

XML:

```
<projects>
    <project pid="p123">
        <leader>
            <name>Amanda</name>
        </leader>
        <analyst>
            <name>Bob</name>
        </analyst>
    </project>
    <project pid="p456">
        <leader>
            <name>John</name>
        </leader>   
    </project>
    <project pid="p789">
        <leader>
            <name>David</name>
        </leader>
        <analyst>
            <name>Amanda</name>
        </analyst>
    </project>
</projects>
```

DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE projects [
<!ELEMENT projects (project*)>
<!ELEMENT project (pid, leader+, analyst*)>
<!ATTLIST project pid ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT leader (name)>
<!ELEMENT analyst (name)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

I have left off the xml version portion of the XML code because this validator only allows one xml version declaration.

If anyone could offer some help it'd be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove pid from the element project:

```
<!ELEMENT project (leader+, analyst*)>
```

A `project` has at least one `leader`, and 0 or more `analyst`. It has no `pid` sub-elements.

A project has a pid *attribute*, which is defined with:

```
<!ATTLIST project pid ID #REQUIRED>
```